# Use a foreach within a new object declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, foreach

So I am working with an api response and I have the following code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
{
    var resources = (JArray) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    var itemStore = resources.Select(r => new ItemObject
    {
        Id = r["Id"].ToString(),
        Title = r["title"].ToString(),
        LongDescription = r["longDescription"].ToString(),
        ShortDescription = r["shortDescription"].ToString(),
        ChildItems = ???
    }).ToList();
}
```

So, where the ??? are, ChildItems is a `List<ItemObject>` that I want to populate from the results contained within `r["ChildItems"]`. How would I loop thru each item and create list to store there? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yest, you could write

```
ChildItems = r["ChildItems"].Select(x=>new ItemObject{Prop1 = x.Prop1, Prop2 = x.Prop2 ... }).ToList()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Don't know why I hadn't thought of that haha